# How to uniquely identify a computer using C#

Tags: c#

[image]

The About box in windows 10 displays a string that uniquely identifies a computer.

Question: How do I find this number with C#? I'm assuming this information exists within the bowels of the namespace System.Management.

I also assume there exists a method to compare that string to the one on a machine (This allows backward compatibility)

PowerShell is fine.

Comment: This resource may be of use to you: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180131-00/?p=97945